# restrict qualifier for different types

Tags: c, restrict-qualifier

I undestand the usefullness of `restrict` in something like

```
void foo(size_t n, double * restrict a, double * restrict b)
```

However, looking into man pages for `printf`, we have:

```
      int fprintf(FILE *restrict stream,
                   const char *restrict format, ...);
```

Both pointers are marked as `restrict`ed, however they point to different types, so in my understanding, they can't be aliases anyway (unless `FILE` is a typedef for `char`), so `restrict` doesn't provide any more information.

Am I correct, or the man page shows a valid usage ?

Comment: A `FILE` could be a struct that contains a `char`. There is no reason why you couldn't pass both a pointer to the whole struct and to the `char` member.

Comment: @dgan, Hmmm, I suspect the `...` arguments are also implied `restrict` and aliasing rules and `char` are special.

Comment: A character type may be used to alias an object defined as any other type (but not vice-versa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Both pointers are marked as `restrict`ed, however they point to
> different types, so in my understanding, they can't be aliases anyway
> (unless `FILE` is a typedef for `char`), so `restrict` doesn't provide any
> more information.
>
> Am I correct, or the man page shows a valid usage ?

You are not correct.

First off, pointer values can be converted to different pointer types, so you cannot assume non-aliasing based on type alone, at least not at the function call interface. The function can, in principle, convert the `FILE *` to a `char *` and use the result to access whatever data are pointed to.  That doesn't even require violating the strict aliasing rule, but depending on the details, it *could* violate `restrict` qualification.

But a more plausible issue in this area would be if `FILE` were a structure type (which it typically is), and the second argument to a call to this function pointed to *a member* of the pointed-to `FILE` structure.  modifications to that member could then violate the `restrict` qualification.

Additionally, you are ignoring that `fprintf()` takes an arbitrary number of additional arguments and that it can, in principle, access external objects.  The non-aliasing requirements imposed by `restrict` are not about pairs of `restrict`-qualified pointers.  They are about individual `restrict`-qualified pointers relative to any other means at all of modifying objects.

Lastly, even if we could somehow conclude from the function signature (contrary to actual fact) that no relevant aliasing was possible, that would not make the use of `restrict` invalid.  It would just be superfluous.